# How to use JNI in a Dynamic web project?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native-methods

I've written a native method to access port. I am able to run the JNI in a simple Java project. However, when I try to run it in a web project, I'm getting an exception like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Comment: where you have kept your library ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you building?  The idea of using a native interface to control a port over the web seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Put your library into one of the following places:

- WEB-INF/lib
- your app server's lib directory
- the JVM lib

I hope that it will work.